# Где ошибка в коде класса Fraction

Tags: python, классы

Создала класс Fraction, не могу понять, где ошибка в коде. Необходимо сложить дробь и целое число? Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться!

```
    def gcd(a,b):                            
    while a%b != 0:
        olda = a
        oldb = b
 
        a = oldb
        b = olda%oldb
    return b
 
class Fraction:
     def __init__(self,a,b):
         self.num = a
         self.den = b
 
     def __str__(self):
         return str(self.num)+"/"+str(self.den)
 
     def show(self):
         print(self.num,"/",self.den)
 
     def __add__(self,otherfraction):
        if not isinstance(self, Fraction):
            return NotImplemented
        if isinstance(otherfraction, Fraction):
            self.num = otherfraction.num
            self.den = otherfraction.den
        elif isinstance(otherfraction, int):
            self.num = otherfraction
            self.den = 1
        else:
            return NotImplemented
            
            newnum = self.num*otherfraction.den + \
                      self.den*otherfraction.num
            newden = self.den * otherfraction.den
            common = gcd(newnum,newden)
            return Fraction(newnum//common,newden//common)
 
print(Fraction(3,5)+3)
```

Со сложением дроби и дроби код работает:

```
    def gcd(a,b):                             
    while a%b != 0:
        olda = a
        oldb = b
 
        a = oldb
        b = olda%oldb
    return b
 
class Fraction:
     def __init__(self,a,b):
         self.num = a
         self.den = b
 
     def __str__(self):
         return str(self.num)+"/"+str(self.den)
 
     def show(self):
         print(self.num,"/",self.den)
 
     def __add__(self,otherfraction):
         newnum = self.num*otherfraction.den + \
                      self.den*otherfraction.num
         newden = self.den * otherfraction.den
         common = gcd(newnum,newden)
         return Fraction(newnum//common,newden//common)
 
   
 
x = Fraction(1,2)
y = Fraction(1,2)
print(x+y)
```

Answer (score 0):

ужас, а не код - в смысле с отступами беда, не знаю на сайте это произошло или реально в коде так было

итак - вот ваш метод сложения

Смотрим что происходит:

```
 def __add__(self,otherfraction):
    # является ли первый параметр сложения дробью
    if not isinstance(self, Fraction):
        return NotImplemented
    # является ли второй параметр сложения дробью
    if isinstance(otherfraction, Fraction):
        self.num = otherfraction.num
        self.den = otherfraction.den
    # является ли второй параметр сложения целым числом
    elif isinstance(otherfraction, int):
        self.num = otherfraction
        self.den = 1
    # является ли второй параметр сложения чем-то другим
    else:
        return NotImplemented
        
        newnum = self.num*otherfraction.den + \
                  self.den*otherfraction.num
        newden = self.den * otherfraction.den
        common = gcd(newnum,newden)
        return Fraction(newnum//common,newden//common)
```

`return` в данном случае возникает только когда второй параметр сложения является и не дробью `Fraction` и не целым числом `int`

ну ок, может это проблема с отступами и надо так:?

```
 def __add__(self,otherfraction):
    # является ли первый параметр сложения дробью
    if not isinstance(self, Fraction):
        return NotImplemented
    # является ли второй параметр сложения дробью
    if isinstance(otherfraction, Fraction):
        self.num = otherfraction.num
        self.den = otherfraction.den
    # является ли второй параметр сложения целым числом
    elif isinstance(otherfraction, int):
        self.num = otherfraction
        self.den = 1
    # является ли второй параметр сложения чем-то другим
    else:
        return NotImplemented
        
    newnum = self.num*otherfraction.den + \
                  self.den*otherfraction.num
    newden = self.den * otherfraction.den
    common = gcd(newnum,newden)
    return Fraction(newnum//common,newden//common)
```

но тогда для целого числа должен быть выполнен код:

```
    newnum = self.num*otherfraction.den + \
                  self.den*otherfraction.num
    newden = self.den * otherfraction.den
    common = gcd(newnum,newden)
    return Fraction(newnum//common,newden//common)
```

но `otherfraction` - это целое число, оно не может быть `otherfraction.den` и т.д.

В общем аккуратнее перепишите код

P.S.

кстати а почему не использовать стандартный НОД из `math`?